# How to get rid of unwanted zigzag effect on edges?

Tags: modifiers

Due to the Solidify Modifier the mesh appears deformed on certain areas. To fix that, I added the Edge Split Modifier, but around the edges in Solid view, appears an unwanted zigzag effect when zoomed-in/out. How can I fix it?

Unwanted zigzag effect
[image]

[image]

If any body know a solution to this problem, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this sort of shift around as you rotate in the viewport?

This looks like a clipping issue. Go into your View tab on the right and muck with the Start and End values under "Clip."

Comment: Yes! That worked! I decreased the End value under Clip to the lowest possible. Thanks!